# How to find Windows driver/program that makes my mouse stop responding

Tags: windows, windows-10, mouse

I'm using Windows 10, and lately, I get sporadic hickups in my desktop where mouse is not responding and appears to jiggle around for few milliseconds.
I chcked with other mouse and it keep occuring (doesn't occur on Linux dual boot), so it's not a HW problem.
I feel like there's a buggy driver / software that has CPU utilization spike that affect me.

How can I find which program / driver cause that ?

Comment: Can you get a mouse driver from the mouse manufacturer?   That is what I do. USB Connected?  Try another USB port.

Comment: the jiggling must be much longer than a few milliseconds if it is noticeable